# calculus - evaluating this double integral with elliptic coordinates

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$\int\int_D xy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy \space\space\space D:=\{(x, y)\in \Bbb R^2:1-x^2\le y^2\le1-\frac{x^2}{4}, x,y\ge0 \} $

Sketching the domain and switching to polar coordinates, I think that the domain is

$D:=\{(\rho, \theta) \in \Bbb R^2 : 1\le\rho\le2, \theta \in[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]\} $

If so, the integral becomes $\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_1^2 2\rho^3\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) \,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta $, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\rho$ doesn't go from $1$ to $2$ at all time, the upper limit of $\rho$ depends on the angle.

Let $y^2 = 1- \frac{x^2}4$

$$\rho^2 = 1-\frac{x^2}4+x^2=1+\frac34x^2=1+\frac34 \rho^2\cos^2\theta$$

$$\rho^2=\frac1{1-\frac34\cos^2\theta}$$

Hence, the upper limit should be $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac34\cos^2\theta}}$$

Edit:

Let $u=1-\frac34 \cos^2 \theta$, $\frac{du}{d\theta}=\frac32\cos \theta\sin \theta$

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\frac{\pi}2\int_1^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac34 \cos^2\theta}}}\rho^3 \cos\theta \sin \theta \,\, d\rho d\theta \\
&=\frac14\int_0^\frac{\pi}2\left( \frac1{(1-\frac34\cos^2 \theta)^2}-1\right)\cos \theta \sin \theta \, d\theta \\
&= \frac14 \int_\frac14^1\frac23\left( \frac1{u^2}-1\right)\, du
\\&= \frac16 [-u^{-1}-u]_\frac14^1\\
&= \frac16 \left(-1+4-1+\frac14\right)\\
&= \frac16 \cdot \frac94\\
&= \frac38
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand one thing, though. Shouldn't $y^2$ be $\rho^2 sin^2(\theta)$ instead of just $\rho^2$?

Comment: I added $x^2$ to both sides, $x^2+y^2=\rho^2$.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: So can you actually solve the problem?

Comment: i have included my working, note that we shouldn't be integrating $2\rho \sin \theta \cos \theta$. $2$ shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the function and the region:

[image]

$\int\limits_{x=0}^1 \int\limits_{y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{1 - x^2/4}} x\ y\ dx\ dy + \int\limits_{x=1}^2 \int\limits_{y=0}^{\sqrt{1 - x^2/4}} x y\ dx\ dy = \frac{3}{8}.$

Comment: Thanks! The integral actually looks easier without elliptic coordinates. Not sure why my textbook recommended using them.